# Other users can't access my svn repo

Tags: svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

Question:
How do I do I set it so that other users can access my svn repo with tortoise?

---

Info:

I have a svn repo set up on my little home server (Ubunt 9.04) and i'm trying to set things up so that my friends and I can work on some programing projects together. Right now I can get my account that i use for admin (we'll call it bob) to access the directory, check out, commit, and all that jazz. But I have a group (Red), with 4 users (littlefoot, joe, winkle,delightful) that i want to have access to this directory. None of them seem to be able to. How can I change this?

I noticed that also littlefoot (my programing alias for this project.) can't create repositories as well. Is there something wrong with the svnadmin setting that i should change?

And yes, I do have folder permissions set up to allow Red to access the folder of the repository.

Comment: Why go through this sort of trouble? Aren't there enough SVN services to suit your needs?

Comment: jldupont - um, not sure what you mean. I'm trying to just get version control that me and my friends can access. if you have a simplier way of doing such, i'll gladly listen. ---------- Martinho - Huh? I'm very new to svn, what does su and sf stand for?

Comment: There are hosted subversion services that will handle the setup and allow your repository to be access online. Two such examples are beanstalk -- http://beanstalkapp.com and google code -- http://code.google.com/projecthosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest setting up a simple [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) server for the repository. It isn't very difficult to set up and you don't need to worry about file permission issues, and I think that it makes dealing with multiple projects and users much easier. The svnserve server isn't as secure as the [Apache WEB_DAV module](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html) since it doesn't communicate with the clients over a secure protocol like HTTPS, but it seems you guys do not need to worry about that with your current environment.

EDIT:
  You will want to edit two files within the `conf` directory where your repository is located. In `svnserv.conf` the above linked guide describes a basic configuration as follows:

```
[general]
password-db = password-file
#anon-acccess = read
#auth-access = write
realm = What you want to call your repository
```

The commented fields above are the default values. They can be set to not allow anonymous access or not allow authorized users to write to the repository among other things.

The `password-db` field has the value `password-file`, thus this file will need to be named the same and contain the users and their passwords as follows:

```
[users]
lightfoot = somepassword
joe = password
...
```

Also note that to access the repository you will need to use the `svn` protocol.

```
svn co svn://server/some_repository
```

Comment: Did you create a file with the users and their passwords? svnserve does require some setup in that regard. I have edited my answer to include more information.

Comment: Thanks very much! now we can finally move ahead on the project. ^_^